# Oracle Apex - adding master - details relation on existing data

Tags: apex

I have master-detail report in Oracle Apex.
I can simply insert details for selected master by clicking 'Add row', but I have some rows in details without link to the master table.
I would like to create this relationship by clicking on my desired master, and now - for example - change behaviour of the 'Add row' button in details region - mayby some pop up windows with rows to select?

Is there any simple way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are describing you have a master detail report that has an interactive grid as detail (there are a couple of different layouts). There is no "out of the box" solution for this, but you can easily create your own. Here is one option:

Create a second detail region where you allow the user to query the orphaned rows (maybe in an interactive report) with a link in each row that would fire a dynamic action which sets the master id for that clicked row.

It's possible to put the detail regions in tabs (using display selector or tab container region)

Comment: Great idea :) I will try prepare dynamic action for this purpose and let you know!

Comment: Ok, I did it using Dynamic Actions and third region. Everything is working! Thanks!